# Reverse proxy Elasticsearch transport port

Tags: nginx, tcp, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy

In my environment, elasticsearch sits on a server that only has standard ports (80, 443, etc.) open. All the other ports are firewalled off. I currently have a reverse proxy on port 80 that reroutes all the elasticsearch HTTP requests to elasticsearch's http port.

I would also like to reroute TCP requests to elasticsearch's [transport port](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html), so that my local client can directly query elasticsearch as a client node. [Nginx 1.9.0](http://nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-1-9-0-and-nginx-plus-r6/) recently allowed TCP load balancing, which is what I would like to utilize for this, but I'm having some trouble getting my system to work. Here is my nginx.conf file (removed the HTTP context to isolate the issue):

```html
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
  server {
    listen      80;
    proxy_pass  127.0.0.1:9300;
  }
}
```

My client node is set up to talk to mydomain.com:80, so it should ideally be routing all traffic to the internal transport port. However, I am getting a the following exceptions: `org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available`

Is there something else I need to configure on my client node or the tcp proxy?

## EDIT 1:

Some additional information. I changed Elasticsearch's transport port from 9300 to 8030, which is a port that is open. When I correspondingly changed my nginx.conf to proxypass to `127.0.0.1:8030` my local client node started working, and got appropriate responses to my queries.

So the issue seems to be that if I'm proxy pass to an already open port, it works, but if the port is closed (9300), the proxy pass fails. Does anyone know why this would be and how to fix it? I'd prefer to stick to using port 9300 if possible.